# Android Studio and Git commit error

Tags: android-studio, git-commit

I made a first git commit from inside an Android Studio project.
It asked me to check for a CR option, i have done that, and it was successful but some files were left again in the Local Changes tab.
Then I tried a second commit and it failed with the same error for all the left files:

> 0 files committed, 46 files failed to commit
>
> Error:warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in gradlew.bat.
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

(Android Studio 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 14.04)

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

According to [JetBrains's blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/04/manage-line-separators-in-intellij-idea-121-like-a-boss/):

You can change the line ending style for the current file in the status bar:

[image]

or

> You can also perform a **bulk change**. Just select a target file or a directory in the project view and choose new separator via Main Menu → **File** → **Line Separator**.